# combinatorics probability of selected letters from the alphabet

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

if fifteen distinct letters are selected at random from 26 letters of the English alphabet, what is the probability that 3 of them are vowels.

I thought since the total outcomes are C(26, 15), then the number of ways to find C(15,3) * C(26,5).

therefore the probability would be C(15,3) * C(26,5)/C(26, 15)

Comment: You are unfortunately incorrect because of an incorrect numerator.  For a correct approach, count how many collections of fifteen letters have exactly three vowels by 1) Pick which three vowels are used, followed by 2) Pick which remaining non-vowels are used.  How many ways are there to pick three vowels?  How many ways can you pick the remaining non-vowels?

Comment: So would that be (5 c 3) * (21 c 12) ? then arrange them by 15 which we would multiply the product by 15!?

Comment: if you multiply the numerator by 15! then you'll need to do that to the denominator too since that would imply you are treating order as relevant and the denominator currently doesn't account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $$\binom{26}{15}$$ ways to select $15$ of the $26$ letters in the English alphabet.

If exactly three of the fifteen selected letters are vowels, the other twelve must be consonants.  The number of ways of selecting three of the five vowels and twelve of the twenty-one consonants in the English alphabet is 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{21}{12}$$

Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{21}{12}}{\dbinom{26}{15}}$$